# ros::Time::now() very different in callback

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am getting very different results when calling ros::Time::now() in the main function and in a Timer's callback function.

I want to get the elapsed time since the Timer began, so I have something like this:

```
ros::Time t_start;

void my_callback(ros::TimerEvent& e)
{
    // In this function, ros::Time::now() returns values greater than 16000
    ros::Duration d_elapsed = ros::Time::now() - t_start; // d_elapsed is huge, e.g. 17108.61000
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialization
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
  ros::NodeHandle handle;

  t_start = ros::Time::now(); // This is always 0.0
  ros::Timer r = handle.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0f/20.0f), my_callback);
  ros::spin();
}
```

When I do `rostopic echo /clock`, I get the large values:

```
---
clock: 
  secs: 20614
  nsecs: 480000000
```

I tried to add a `ros::spinOnce()` before initialization t_start, but that did not change anything.

The rosparam `/use_sim_time` is true because I'm using Gazebo.

Why are the values returned from `ros::Time::now()` so different?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263284/ros::time::now()-very-different-in-callback/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2017-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-06**:
Can you include the initialization?  `now()` shouldn't be zero.

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2017-06-06**:
Sure, although it is just an init call and declaring a NodeHandle. I do create some service clients after the initialization, but I don't think those should matter. I edited the question to include a couple more details too.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-06**:
If gazebo is publishing /clock then it will start at zero when it launches, then count up as long as it is running.  It looks like you have been running it for more than 5 hours- is that true?  Also do you print or publish the time difference every callback, otherwise how did you know d_elapsed?

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2017-06-06**:
Yes, Gazebo was running for more than 5 hours. I just leave it on in between tests (resetting positions and odometry). I print the elapsed time at each callback for testing purposes. I need to use the elapsed time to get the index of trajectory points.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-06**:
t_start is likely always zero because the node hasn't yet had a chance to receive a message on /clock, so the node believes the time is zero. If you add in a sleep and spinOnce() before giving t_start a value it should be initialized with the value of the message received on /clock.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-07**:
@ufr3c_tjc you should put that in an answer

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2017-06-07**:
@ufr3c_tjc yep that was it. Thanks! I only needed to add a sleep before calling Time::now(). I'm glad it was a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From earlier comment:

t_start is likely always zero because the node hasn't yet had a chance to receive a message on /clock, so the node believes the time is zero. If you add in a sleep and spinOnce() before giving t_start a value it should be initialized with the value of the message received on /clock.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4